# Where can I find the Google+ API?

Tags: google-plus

I am planing to write some apps with Google+. Where can I find its API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's up:

http://developers.google.com/+/api/

Answer (score 7):

There's no public API yet.  You can sign up to get notified on developments:

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API at the moment. You can sign up [here](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/) to get more information when it is available.

Answer (score 1):

Google:
http://developers.google.com/+/api/
Free Google Plus API eBook:
http://www.heronote.com/files/Google-Plus.htm

Answer (score -2):

Use following link:
[Google Plus API Implementation in PHP](http://3aroundweb.in/google-plus-api-implemntation-in-php/).